# Using lambda expressions with Rythm Engine

Tags: java, rythm

I'm trying to use lambda expressions with Rythm Engine and it's working in most cases. However, it isn't working when I invoke a tag inside a lambda expression.

Simplest example:

```
@test(x -> blabla(x) )

@def test(java.util.function.Function f) {
    @f.apply("Test")
}

@def blabla(String text) {
    ...
    Test: @text
    ...
}
```

If I use string concatenation in the lambda expression, it works perfectly, but in my real code I need to invoke a complex tag.

Does anybody know how I can do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution.

Revising the generated java code, it can be seen that the function called "blabla" (sorry, stupid name) has the signature:

```
public org.rythmengine.utils.RawData blabla(String text)
```

So, the way to make it work is calling "RawData.toString()".

The solution is:

```
@test(x -> blabla( x.toString() )

@def test(java.util.function.Function<String, String> f) {
    @f.apply("Test")
}

@def blabla(String text) {
    ...
    Test: @text
    ...
}
```

To prevent unnecessary castings, I add the arguments "String, String" to the generic class "java.util.function.Function".

To test the code, it's useful to define the environment variable "home.tmp.dir" and use a raw CodeType:

```
Map<String, Object> conf = new HashMap<>();
conf.put("home.tmp.dir", "./rythm/"); // Generated code

RythmEngine engine = new RythmEngine(conf);
engine.prepare(ICodeType.DefImpl.RAW);
```